# Find Gal$(f)$, here $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\Bbb{Q}(x^6)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $f$ be the minimal polynomial of $x\in \Bbb{Q}(x)$ over $\Bbb{Q}(x^6)$. How to find the Galois group of $f$?

Here is my thought, $f(t)=t^6-x^6$ is the minimal polynomial. Factor it out, we can get the splitting field for $f$ is $\Bbb{Q}(x,\sqrt{3}ix)$. Then I got stuck, how to find the degree of the extension $[\Bbb{Q}(x,\sqrt{3}ix):\Bbb{Q}(x^6)]$ and how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is preferable to say that the splitting field is $L=K(x,\zeta_6)$, where $\zeta_6$ is a primitive $6$-th root of $1$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(x^6)$. Now $[K(x,\zeta_6):K(x)]$ has degree $\leq 2$. But $K(x)=\mathbb{Q}(x^6)$ does not contain any imaginary complex number, so the degree is actually $2$, and then $[L:K]=[L:K(x)][K(x):K]=2\times 6=12$.

Now $K(x,\zeta_6)/K(\zeta_6)$ is a Kummer extension of degree $6$, hence its Galois group is cyclic. This subgroup is normal because it has index $2$.

Moreover, $K(x)/K$ is not a normal extension, so the Galois group contains a non normal subgroup of order $2$. In particular, it is not abelian. The only non abelian group of order $12$ with a normal cyclic subgroup of order $6$ is $D_6$, so $Gal(f)\simeq D_6$.

You can also see it more explicitely by considering $\sigma:L\to L$ such that $\sigma(x)=\zeta_6 x$ and $\sigma(\zeta_6)=\zeta_6$, and $\tau:L\to L$
 such that $\tau(x)=x$ and $\tau\zeta_6)=\zeta_6^{-1}$. You can easily check that $\sigma$ has order $6$, $\tau$ has order $2$ and $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}=\sigma^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

The splitting field for $ f $ is $ \mathbb{Q}(x, \sqrt{3}ix) = \mathbb{Q}(x, \sqrt{3}i) $, and the extension degree is $ [\mathbb{Q}(x, \sqrt{3}i) : \mathbb{Q}(x^6)] = [\mathbb{Q}(x, \sqrt{3}i) : \mathbb{Q}(x)][\mathbb{Q}(x) : \mathbb{Q}(x^6)] = 2 \cdot 6 = 12 $.

Conjugates of $ x $ over $ \mathbb{Q}(x^6) $ are $ x $, $ e^{\pi i/3} x $, $ \dots $, $ e^{5\pi i/3} x $, which are the possible values of $ \sigma(x) $ for $ \sigma \in \operatorname{Gal}(f) $. Similarly, the possible values of $ \sigma(\sqrt{3}i) $ are $ \pm\sqrt{3}i $. Since $ \sigma $ is determined by these values and $ \lvert\operatorname{Gal}(f)\rvert = [\mathbb{Q}(x, \sqrt{3}i) : \mathbb{Q}(x)] = 12 $, these possible $ 12 $ patterns actually appear. We can now determine $ \operatorname{Gal}(f) $.